# Build weighted matrix in MATLAB with vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, indexing

I have a problem using MATLAB. I want to create a huge adjacency matrix and to achieve this result I wrote some code that generates 3 vectors: `NodeX`, `NodeY`, and `Weight`.

`NodeX` represents the row indexes of the matrix.

`NodeY` represents the column indexes of the matrix.

`Weight` is a vector that contains the weights.

All these vectors are put into a `.csv` file that MATLAB reads very easily. But when I create the matrix I have a problem. This is the code that I use to associate indexes to weights.

```
    for i=1:1:3873
    WeightedMatrix(NodeY(i), NodeX(i)) = Weight(i);
    end
```

The results I see are a little bit strange to me. In fact if I do:

```
WeightedMatrix(NodeY(1), NodeX(1))
```

MATLAB prints to me:

```
ans = 0.2483
```

Which is a value that is present into the Weight vector but it's not the value I want.

And if I do:

```
Weight(1)
```

It returns `ans = 1.2550` (which is the value I want).

These three vectors are for example:

[image: Data Imported from .Csv]

This is the final part that creates the `.csv` file:

```
tmp = set(Final)
tmp = tuple(tmp)
for z in tmp:
print str(z[0]) + "," + str(z[1]) + "," + str(z[2]) + "\n"
```

Comment: In `WeightedMatrix(NodeY(1), NodeX(1))` shouldn't you change the order of arguments if you want to see the same result as `Weight(1)`?

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same.. Thank you

Comment: I think you should share the part of your code where you read / generate the three vectors.

Comment: @erfan I added the final code. If you want all the code please tell me.

Comment: If you can successfully read all 3 vectors NodeX, NodeY and Weigth, can't you try this...: 

`WMatrix = zeros(max(NodeX), max(NodeY));`
`WMatrix(NodeX , NodeY) = Weigth`

Comment: Have you understood the erfan's comment ? Because in your example you you create a matrix with M(A,B) = C and then you call M(B,A)... So edit your question if this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: @obchardon edited. Thanks.

Comment: @PhoenixBlue I tried to follow what you wrote but Matlab gives me an error: Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Answer (score 0):

You can form  adjacency matrix as a sparse matrix to prevent memory problem:

```
WeightedMatrix_sp = sparse(NodeX, NodeY, Weight);
```

If you have enough memory you can convert sparse matrix to dense matrix:

```
WeightedMatrix = full(WeightedMatrix_sp);
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not a problem of memory, I managed to make the results with only ones and no weights, but my problem consists of matching weights with indexes. Thank you one more time...

Comment: @RiccardoCelli if you want ones instead of weights please add your condition to the question .you can write : `WeightedMatrix =full(sparse(NodeX, NodeY, 1));`

Comment: No I want weights. The problem is not with numbers but with elements of the vector Weight. :)

Comment: I tried to use your method but the result is different to previous two I put in my question so I think it doesn't work in my case. Thanks a lot.